# Multiprocessing a Python function in a loop

Tags: python

I have a lack of performance with this function :

```
def update(self, request):
    result = "Eat fruits!"
    status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    fruits = Fruits.objects.all
    for fruit in fruits:
        try:
            models.Fruits.save(fruits, call_basket=True)
        except:
            pass
    return JsonResponse(result, status_code)
```

This line `models.Fruits.save(fruits, call_basket=True)` is very slow so I'd like to use muliprocessing to accelerate the process. In spite of the documentation I don't know how to put it in my code.

How can I use `multiprocessing.Process` in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Django?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate each group with the multiprocessing.

Modified code for separating each fruit in group process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Fruits

def save_fruit(fruit):
    try:
        fruit.save(call_basket=True)
    except:
        pass

def update(self, request):
    result = "Eat fruits!"
    status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    fruits = Fruits.objects.all()

    processes = []
    for fruit in fruits:
        p = Process(target=save_fruit, args=(fruit,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    return JsonResponse(result, status_code)
```

Comment: Thank you NIKUJN KOTHIYA for your reply. My IDE complains because the target is considered as an unresolved reference. Do you know why?

Comment: code update to fix the issue of the unresolved `save_fruit()` function before the update.